# WINE not working on external monitor

Tags: nvidia, wine, multiple-monitors

Certain games/applications on WINE work fine on my primary display, but just freeze (display wise) on my external monitor. They still function (ie: arrow keys result in sounds and things) and if I drag it back to primary the display returns.

I'm not sure where to start with this. I have a DELL M3800 with Ubuntu 14.04. It has a switching intel/nvidia chipset thing... I have configured NVIDIA X Server Settings PRIME profile to be "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)".

Also, Firefox WebGL works on both monitors which makes me think acceleration might be working on both (although Chromium WebGL doesn't work at all).

My google-fu has failed me too. :)

Comment: I have a similar issue with NVIDIA Driver Version: 515.105.01 and NVML Version: 11.515.105.01. If I switch to power savings mode (Intel) winecfg starts, if I switch to On Demand it error's out:
0e4:err:winediag:nodrv_CreateWindow Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded.